# Keep responsive image same height and centered within image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to keep a main banner on my page the same height as the browser window shrinks.  I would like the left / right sides to end up being cut off and the banner to always focus on the center of the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/ab4p4aaj/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="home">
        <img src="http://www.lightswitchcreative.ca/_images/mainslide.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="mainslide" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thnik if you set him height: 50px; in css it will remain.

Comment: just remove the class img-responsive

Comment: If I add a height on the image in CSS, it distorts the image when it's shrunk.  The width / height ratio is off.

Comment: If I remove img-responsive the image does not stay centered on the middle portion of the image when shrunk.  I end up just seeing the very right hand side when shrunk down to a mobile size.

Comment: then set the width @media

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/ab4p4aaj/1/

Comment: @user1110562 May you consider accept as answer if it helps

Answer (score 2):

Replace your image by a div:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="home">
        <div id="mainslider"></div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And add the image as background using `background-size: cover`

```
#mainslider {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(http://www.lightswitchcreative.ca/_images/mainslide.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ab4p4aaj/4/)